# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebcli'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I tried to check the version of aws elastic-beanstalk by 'eb --version' in visual studio code terminal, there happened an error : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebcli'.** How to solve this problem?

#### Terminal:

**input** :

```
$ eb --version
```

**output** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/likelion_MC/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/Scripts/eb", 
line 12, in <module>
    import ebcli.core.ebcore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebcli'
```

### This is my eb file:

```
import sys
import ebcli.core.ebcore

def main():
    return ebcli.core.ebcore.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Are you using virtual env and did you make sure to enable it?

Comment: Yes, I installed it by 'python -m venv myvenv'

Comment: As @cagrias suggests, I don't think you've activated the venv ... either that or you've installed eb outside "myvenv" by mistake.

Comment: @urbanespaceman I did what you'd suggested, but It was not solved.

Comment: If you list the packages you're using with command `pip freeze` does `eb` show?

Comment: Agree that VE is suspect. Also, IDEs usually need to be set up to use the VE as interpreter.  Drop the IDE use and activate / import in command line alone. Try what Original BBQ said, but in VENV terminal, not IDE

Comment: @OriginalBBQSauce Yeah... I checked whether it was installed, but it didn't. So, I installed it by `pip install eb`. However, the problem is unsolved.

Comment: @MCbot So, as the others, I think the problem is that either you haven't activated your virtual environment or are installing the packages globally rather than in the environment. IMO, I dislike venv exactly because of these confusions. I switched to pipenv (https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/), which unites pip and venv under the same commands and haven't got a problem like this ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the comments, you have a virtual environment. To activate it in Visual Studio:

> #### Activate an existing virtual environment
>
> If you've already created a virtual environment elsewhere, you can activate it for a project as follows:
>
> 1. Right-click Python Environments in Solution Explorer and select Add Environment.
> 2. In the Browse dialog that appears, navigate to and select the folder that contains the virtual environment, and select OK. If Visual Studio detects a requirements.txt file in that environment, it asks whether to install those packages.
> 3. After a few moments, the virtual environment appears under the Python Environments node in Solution Explorer. The virtual environment is not activated by default, so right-click it and select Activate Environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/selecting-a-python-environment-for-a-project?view=vs-2019

In Visual Studio Code:

> To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

To test if your virtual environment is working, you should go to the command line and activate it and then ensure `ebcli` is installed. First, `cd` into your project directory.

Unix:

```
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install ebcli
```

Windows:

```
C:\> myvenv\Scripts\activate.bat
C:\> pip install ebcli
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the hashbang on the first line of the eb script

If you open the script `/Users/john/.ebcli-virtual-env/bin/eb`, you will notice that python3 in the hashbang is hardcoded to global python3 `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`.

While the installation script is installing in a virtualenv, the main command script is still referring to the global python.

I just changed it to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and everything worked.